# How to send data from android device to arduino adk

Tags: android, arduino, adk

Our team at the office need to incorporate data transfer between Android device and Arduino adk, along both ways. However, we could not find enough information about sending data from the Android device to the Arduino adk. The reverse way has been completed. Can anyone please suggest any link or tutorial from where we can get such a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://allaboutee.com/2011/12/31/arduino-adk-board-how-send-data-from-the-board-to-the-android-device/

and you can used any sensor like NFS or WIF OR BlueTo

Comment: Could you put a summary of the article in your answer please?  Links die sometimes and it'll mean this answer will stay useful for others.